# "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:" While Installing PyTorch in Anaconda

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

When trying to install PyTorch inside an Anaconda environment with the command `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`, I get the error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch
  - cudatoolkit=11.6
  - torchaudio

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.,
```

I also tried adding conda-forge to my list of channels and got the same error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have a 32 bit version of anaconda. You need to uninstall and install a 64 bit version to have access to these packages